# object value is only increasing in the first element of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, element

I am making a simple inventory app where I get stuck while increasing the stock. If I try to increase stock it's only working for the first element, not any other element, and if I try to increase any other element stock it again increases stock in first element of the array

1. Only increasing value of the first element of the array
2. If I choose any other item code it again chooses the first element and increase value in the first element

```js
// Constructor For Products
    
    var item = function(name,itemCode,stock){
        this.name = name;
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
        this.stock = stock;
    }
    
    var data = [];
    
    function addItem(name,itemCode,stock){
        if (data.map(i => i.itemCode).includes(itemCode)) return alert('you enter a duplicate itemcode'),menu();
        var Newitem = new item(name,itemCode,stock);
        data.push(Newitem);
    }
    
    
    //Delete item
function delItem(n){
    if (data.map(i => i.itemCode).includes(n)){
        var getIndex = data.indexOf(n)+1;
        data.pop(getIndex);
    }else{
        alert('This item is not in the database')
    }
    }
    
 
   
    
    
    //Increase stock
     item.prototype.inc = function(j){
        return this.stock = this.stock + j;
    }
    function incItem(n,val){
    if (data.map(i => i.itemCode).includes(n)){
        var getIndex = data.indexOf(n)+1;
        let lmn = data[getIndex].inc(val);
         return lmn;
    }else{
        alert('This item is not in the database')
    }
    }
    
    
    addItem('BlueTee',100,50);
    addItem('Yellow tee',101,100);
    addItem('BrownTee',102,120);
```

Comment: you may consider provide a more useful snippet

Comment: which kind of snippet?

Comment: the code is not functional inside the snippet

Comment: i simply counstruct the object and add the object into the data array now i want to increase value dynammically so i create a function incitem

Comment: oh sorry because of this var item = function(name,itemCode,stock){
        this.name = name;
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

Comment: its not running in the snippet

Comment: Nothing in your code sets the prototype of the objects to `item.prototype`.

Comment: plz add this var item = function(name,itemCode,stock){
        this.name = name;
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

Comment: i forget to add that line

Comment: So edit the question and add it.

Comment: function addItem(name,itemCode,stock){
        if (data.map(i => i.itemCode).includes(itemCode)) return alert('you enter a duplicate itemcode'),menu();
        var Newitem = new item(name,itemCode,stock);
        data.push(Newitem);
    }

Comment: where is the option to edit my question i cant find that i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: search "edit" you will find in page, just below you question

Comment: now please check the code i done that

Comment: Please check my answer,  i have clean up little bit for your refence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating the problem. You can, for example, use the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the first element in the array and then just increment it's stock property by `val`, something like:

```js
data = [
  { name: "BlueTee", itemCode: 100, stock: 50 },
  { name: "Yellow tee", itemCode: 101, stock: 100 },
  { name: "BrownTee", itemCode: 102, stock: 120 },
];

function incItem(n, val) {
  let item = data.find((p) => p.itemCode === n);
  if (item) {
    item.stock += val;
    return item;
  } else {
    console.log("This item is not in the database");
  }
}

console.log(incItem(102, 5));
incItem(666, 10);
```

Comment: thanks bro its working but why do you take p as parameter in find???

Comment: i am sorry its my bad i dont see it was an arrow function

Comment: Check the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). That `p` is just a random variable name that I gave to the current element in the array.

Comment: yeah i got it actually i am just learnig and builduing some stuff and learning technique and thanks buddy for the help

Comment: okah and i am new to stack so i dont know about these things so i did it now

Answer (score 1):

If you really learning to learn basic of `class`, `methods`. Look for `array.find` implementation.

Below given code, you can refer as small clean up to your code.

```js
class Item {
  constructor(name, itemCode, stock) {
    this.name = name;
    this.itemCode = itemCode;
    this.stock = stock;
    this.list = [];
  }
  inc(n) {
    return (this.stock += n);
  }
}
class ItemInventory {
  constructor() {
    this.list = [];
  }

  addItem(name, itemCode, stock) {
    const item = this.list.find((item) => item.itemCode === itemCode);
    if (item) return alert("you enter a duplicate itemcode"), menu();
    this.list.push(new Item(name, itemCode, stock));
  }
  findAndInc(n, val) {
    const item = this.list.find((item) => item.itemCode === val);
    if (item) {
      item.inc(n);
      return item;
    } else {
      alert("This item is not in the database");
    }
  }
}
const inventory = new ItemInventory();
inventory.addItem("BlueTee", 101, 50);
inventory.addItem("Yellow tee", 102, 38);
inventory.addItem("Brown tee", 103, 89);
console.log(inventory.list);
inventory.findAndInc(5, 101);
console.log(inventory.list);
```

Comment: yeah for sure i really like to see more as i am begginer now so i will learn more techniques thanks buddy for the help

Comment: Nice .. :-) Good luck